# Angular Modal not always showing properly

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

We implemented a custom error-handling in our Angular 4 app, which overrides the default ErrorHandler and shows a modal with the error:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorCatcherService implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private errorDispatcherService: ErrorDispatcherService) { }

  public handleError(error: Error) {
    this.errorDispatcherService.dispatchError(error);
  }
}
```

Skipping some steps, we then have a ErrorDisplayService, which gets the informations about the error and shows a NgbModal, which is a Component from the @ng-bootstrap framework:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorDisplayService {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
  }

  public showError(errorInformation: ErrorInformation): void {
    const options = <NgbModalOptions>{
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: true
    };

    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ErrorDisplayContentComponent, options);
    const componentInstance = <ErrorDisplayContentComponent>modalRef.componentInstance;
    componentInstance.initialize(errorInformation);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this works only half of the time: The expected result is sometimes correct, for example:

[image]

But more often than not, what we get is something like that:
[image]

All my tinkering didn't work so far and I couldn't pin down the problem. Are there further possibilities around I could try to make this work?

Comment: I've seen similar problems with the modal backdrop appearing but the modal not and have noticed console errors. Have you checked the console for any errors?

Answer (score 5):

I decided to implement error handler in similar way and faced with the same problem. By using debugger, I found out that handleError() function is invoked by angular **outside** of `Zone`, so I assumed this could be a cause that `NgbModalWindow` is not rendered correctly.

My solution was to open modal **inside** angular `zone`. And that helped.

Try this:

1. Inject into your `ErrorHandler` implementation `NgZone`. (`private zone: NgZone` into constructor) or with `injector`.
2. Wrap your `this.errorDispatcherService.dispatchError(error);` into `zone.run(() => this.errorDispatcherService.dispatchError(error));`